# DialogFlow wrong year when no year is specified

Tags: datetime, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, voice, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am currently trying to create my own Google Agent using DialogFlow and while everything is going fine, I am finding myself unable to solve the smallest of problems.

Google has a tendency to add an additional year to the datetime object whenever I state a date. An example:
If I say "How much did we produce 29/6?" (6/29 doesn't work either) it will grab the date and format it correctly to the 6th of June, however it will make it year **2021** instead of **2020**... Is there any way to make it default to our current year, unless I specifically say a different year?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try saying "How much did we produce on June 29th?" I think it may have some issue processing the string "29/6" and somehow it gets translated to 6th of June.

You had mentioned "6th of June" is formatted correctly when giving "29/6", shouldn't it be "29th of June"?